# Magento Top Links Login class disappears randomly!

Tags: magento-1.9, login, toplinks, class

So I have slightly modified the customer.xml file to add classes to the top links, so I could add font awesome icons to them. The issue I am having is for some reason the login class disappears if I click on the login link, then without actually logging in, click back to the home page, the class on the login link get removed!

```
<reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>Login</label>
            <url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/>
            <title>Login</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>12</position>
            <liParams>
                <class>toplinks-login</class>
            </liParams>
            <aParams>
                <class>toplinks-login-a</class>
            </aParams>
            <beforeText/>
            <afterText/>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

This is the code I have for the login. So when the problem happens the "toplinks-login-a" class disappears and no class is shown at all.

I have searched for hours and can't find out why this could happen. Does anyone know another alternate way to add a class, perhaps hardcoding it?

EDIT:
This is what the HTML looks like when the page loads correctly

```
<a href="http://website.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cDovL2Rldi5uYXVnaHR5Y292ZS5jb20vbWFzdHVyYmF0b3JzLmh0bWw,/" title="Login" class="toplinks-login-a">Login</a>
```

And when it doesn't work randomly

```
<a href="http://website.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cDovL2Rldi5uYXVnaHR5Y292ZS5jb20v/" title="http://website.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cDovL2Rldi5uYXVnaHR5Y292ZS5jb20v/">Log In</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

add them like this `<liParams>class="toplinks-login"</liParams><aParams>class="toplinks-login-a"</aParams>`

```
 <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
                <label>Login</label>
                <url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/>
                <title>Login</title>
                <prepare/>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>12</position>
    <liParams>class="toplinks-login"</liParams>
    <aParams>class="toplinks-login-a"</aParams>
    <beforeText/>
                <afterText/>
            </action>
        </reference>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it still doesn't fix it. The odd thing is I have changed the default "Log In" text to "Login" and when the class disappears it also changes the text back to "Log In". Also after more testing, it seems to just randomly disappear, not just after clicking back off login page.

Comment: are you using any custom theme?

Comment: I am using a custom theme, but nothing that would override anything to do with the login function, I already checked every theme file. Also, I am using exact same setup on my localhost and my dev server and I don't have this problem on my localhost copy :/

Comment: did you tried default theme have a same problem?

Comment: `admin -> system ->configuration ->customer configuration`  tab `login option`
`Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in` set to yes

Comment: Tried that already, still not working :(